# need help to map ViewModel to Entity using AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I am new to automapper.  need some help to map from ViewModel to Entity.

Here's my user entity

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

here's my ViewModel

```
public class UserViewModel
{

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I create a map. its not working

```
        CreateMap<UserLoginViewModel, User>()
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.CreatedDate, DateTime.Now)
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.DisplayName, "");
```

DisplayName and CreatedDate are required fields. since its not in the ViewModel, I will make DisplayName = "" and CreateDate = datetime.now.

I want to know if I can do it using the automapper, or I have to do it after the mapping.

please show me some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you have UserViewModel view model and User entity however your mapping configuration contains third type - UserLoginViewModel. Supposing that UserLoginViewModel is the same as UserViewModel, you should change you configuration as below.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>()
        .ForMember(dest=>dest.CreatedDate, t=> t.MapFrom(s=> DateTime.Now))
        .ForMember(dest=>dest.DisplayName, t=> t.MapFrom(s=> ""));
```

[AutoMapper wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki).